# Microsoft teams bot - could not parse tenant id

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a bot for MS Teams, and running into an issue. When trying to initiate a conversation from the bot, I get this error:

> Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Could not parse tenant id

I haven't been able to find anywhere in the docs that mentions a required Tenant ID, and I never set one up in the application.  How can I specify this, or is the root cause something else?

Below is the code I am using that returns the error (strings obfuscated).

```
private ConversationResourceResponse GetConversation(IActivity activity)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        var userAccount = new ChannelAccount("user@domain.com");
        var botAccount = new ChannelAccount("@botHandle", "botName");

        var conversationId = connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversation(botAccount, userAccount);
        return conversationId;
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special behaviour in MS Teams when you want to create a conversation, so you have to use a specific method provided by MS Teams NuGet package:

```
// Create or get existing chat conversation with user
var response = client.Conversations.CreateOrGetDirectConversation(activity.Recipient, activity.From, activity.GetTenantId());
```

You can see that the method has the `tenantId` in parameter.

The NuGet package is called `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams` and is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams).

More details on the MS Teams documentation (it's not detailed on Bot framework side):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/scenarios/bots-personal-conversations#starting-a-11-conversation

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had the Microsoft.Bot.Connector package, but did not know about Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.  Solved that error!

Comment: Just a note: the mentioned package has now been deprecated and you should use package Microsoft.Bot.Builder with method `CreateConversationAsync`